# Adding attachment name to message body

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-word

I hope someone can help me with this. A few months ago I was able to write a macro for Outlook 2003 to add the filenames of all the attachment in an email message, which I really need for my line of work.

However, if I switch the default editor to Word, the macro doesn't even appear; I guess it has to be incorporated into Word's normal.dot or something. If I add it to VB from Word, I can see the macro, but I get all sorts of errors.

Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction for this. My current macro, which works in "normal" Outlook messages (not those created with Word Editor) is this:

```
Sub Names()

Dim Atmt As Attachment
Dim Mensaje As Outlook.MailItem
Dim Adjuntos As String


Set Mensaje = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
Mensaje.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
i = 0
Adjuntos = ""

For Each Atmt In Mensaje.Attachments
    'If Atmt.Size > 5 Then
    Adjuntos = "<HMTL> ** Attached file: <u> " & Atmt.FileName & " </u> </html> <br>" & vbNewLine & Adjuntos
    i = i + 1
    'End If
Next Atmt

Adjuntos = "<HMTL> <u> <b> Total number of attached files: " & i & "</u></b> </html> <br>" & Adjuntos & vbNewLine

Mensaje.HTMLBody = Adjuntos & Mensaje.HTMLBody

Set Mensaje = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the two code blocks below is simply the linking of the Outlook object library. In Outlook, this is not necessary, but from Word, you need to either include the library as a reference to your Word project, or else use late binding (the method I demonstrate below).

Late binding links the Outlook library to an object in your code/project, `OLK` in this case, and allows you to use the associated functions without needing to perform any additional steps/save any additional files.

Linking the library should also work, but since this is not a normal Word project that you can reference later/a new Word project is created for each new email, I'm thinking (though I did not test) that you would need to include the code in your `Normal` template, which means that code will be available on **any** Word document you create, unless you specify a different template.

This may or may not be what you want to do, but if it is, then just past the Outlook code into your `Normal` template and [link the Outlook library as a reference](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/missingreferences.aspx).

---

### From *MS Outlook* (preferred method)

This will work, even with WORD as the email editing application, when pasted into an OUTLOOK project:

```
Option Explicit 

Sub Names()

Dim Atmt As Attachment
Dim Mensaje As Outlook.MailItem
Dim Adjuntos As String
Dim Body As String
Dim i As Integer


Set Mensaje = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
Mensaje.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML

Body = Mensaje.HTMLBody

i = 0
Adjuntos = ""

For Each Atmt In Mensaje.Attachments
    'If Atmt.Size > 5 Then
    Adjuntos = Adjuntos & "** Attached file: <u> " & Atmt.FileName & " </u> <br>"
    i = i + 1
    'End If
Next Atmt

Adjuntos = "<u> <b> Total number of attached files: " & i & "</u></b> <br>" & Adjuntos

Mensaje.HTMLBody = Left(Body, InStr(Body, "</body>") - 1) & Adjuntos & Right(Body, Len(Body) - InStr(Body, "</body>") + 4)

Set Mensaje = Nothing

End Sub
```

---

### From *MS Word*/Within the new mail item

I was able to get the following to work, but you should note that I got security warnings (normal, unavoidable AFAIK) that must be pushed through with user intervention.

Paste the below into your WORD project (open mail item) and run it. You should also be able to put this in the `Normal` template, but that means the macro will *always* be available, which may or may not be a problem for you.

```
Sub Names()

Dim OLK As Object 'Oulook.Application
Dim Atmt As Object 'Attachment
Dim Mensaje As Object 'Outlook.MailItem
Dim Adjuntos As String
Dim Body As String
Dim i As Integer

Set OLK = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set Mensaje = OLK.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
Mensaje.BodyFormat = 2 'olFormatHTML

Body = Mensaje.HTMLBody

i = 0
Adjuntos = ""

For Each Atmt In Mensaje.Attachments
    'If Atmt.Size > 5 Then
    Adjuntos = Adjuntos & "** Attached file: <u> " & Atmt.FileName & " </u> <br>"
    i = i + 1
    'End If
Next Atmt

Adjuntos = "<u> <b> Total number of attached files: " & i & "</u></b> <br>" & Adjuntos

Mensaje.HTMLBody = Left(Body, InStr(Body, "</body>") - 1) & Adjuntos & Right(Body, Len(Body) - InStr(Body, "</body>") + 4)

Set OLK = Nothing
Set Mensaje = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. With this, I'm getting a compile error: "Method or data member not found." regarding the ActiveInspector part.

Comment: @user1574581 I should have added that this code was placed in a module within the Outlook project, not Word (i.e. not directly in the mail message). Does this help? If not, there should be some other ways to get around that error. Let me know and I will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: The thing is, the VB Editor seems to open a Word project in my case (since I'm using Word as the email editor). Thanks again

Comment: @Xyberg dorry for the delay... Open Outlook, press <ALT>-<F11>, then enter the code there. Once done, *then* run your macro. If you are trying to trigger this from the active message window, then this can be done from word, but the process is slightly more complicated. Let me know, and I can start working on guiding you in that direction!

Comment: No problem! I have no particular rush for this and I'd hate to bother. I did enter the first code I posted here the way you just told me, and that works fine if I don't use Word as the email editor. The problem comes when I do use Word as the editor, and then, when I press alt+F8 to run macros from the active message window, I only get the macros entered into Word's VB editor.

Comment: Ah. You should be able to open the VBE from **Outlook** and run the code and have it work. Regardless, I'll whip up how to do it from Word as well.

Comment: Sorry I didn't answer before.

This one works! I can't thank you enough. I had cracked my head over this once and again. I only dabble in programming and this is awesome.

THANKS!

Comment: @Xyberg No problem, glad I could help! If this answer is helpful to you, then please consider marking it as the accepted answer to others may more easily find it in the future.